# What is this message and how do I stop it from appearing?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machines

I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.04.2 on Oracle Virtual Box 7.0.8 r156879 that's on a Windows 10 Machine. Every time I start the VM I get this message that's in the image. How do I stop this from appearing? I doesn't appear with servers that I connect to on AWS or Oracle. Needless to say, it messes with the login.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Quoting [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1321970/680869) answer:

> One item you may want to look at is disabling the early boot stage as
> it can sometimes lead to this sort of problem on some server
> installations depending on the system's configuration. To do this,
> create an empty file named `cloud-init.disabled` in the `/etc/cloud/`
> directory:
>
> `sudo touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled`
>
> This will not have any negative impact on the system's ability to
> boot. You can read more about [the early boot stages
> here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/boot.html) if
> there are other settings that you would like to tweak.